# How do I determine the phase lag for a tide

Tags: tides

I want to determine the height of a sine wave for some tidal constituents for which I would use the following equation: ()=cos⁡(−), where H is the amplitude,  is the speed of rotation, t is the time elapsed and  is the phase lag. If I have got the following data for a site, how do I determine the phase lag so that I can calculate Y(t).

Constituent M2, Amplitude 3.18, Degrees per hour 28.984, Radians per hour 0.5058, Phase degree 173

Comment: Worth checking up on... is this a homework question (or where are you getting the data, may be of interest to people, if not)

Comment: And are you needing to produce the entire time function of height, or just the "height of the sine wave" (which isn't as involved at all)

Comment: It is from a paper Swansea Bay Tidal Lagoon Annual Energy Estimation by Petley and Aggidis. I was just wanting to work out the height of the sine wave to then use in energy estimates with coding

Comment: So more than just the peak height (which is of course the amplitude) I take it!  (Hopefully you can understand why I had a wonder if it was a homework question, many times in undergrad they'd ask questions like that, wanting the max height, and giving a fairly involved trig function, and people would get lost trying to compute it all , when it's right there given by the amplitude).  But sorry, have no more clue than that, upvoted, as it's an interesting looking question